# Pandas duplicate rows based on list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have a `pd.Series` of list items. I define two locations to be duplicates if they have one or more list items in common. This definition should be *transitive*, meaning that if locations `A` and `B` are duplicates, and locations `B` and `C` are duplicates, then locations `A` and `C` are duplicates.

Examples:

```
In [117]: df
Out[117]: 
        A  dupe_group_ix
0  [A, B]              0
1  [D, X]              0
2     [B]              0
3  [D, A]              0
4     [A]              0
```

All rows are duplicates. Note that row `0` and `1` are duplicates because row `0` and `3` are duplicates, as are row `1` and `3`.

```
In [125]: df
Out[125]: 
        A  dupe_group_ix
0  [A, B]              0
1  [D, X]              1
2     [B]              0
3  [K, D]              1
4     [A]              0
```

In this examples, there are two separate groups of duplicates.

Comment: So it means all rows are duplicated? Because `A` is in `0,4` index, `B` in `0,2`, `D` in `1, 3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper function to map the group id:

```
grp = {'_':-1}
def map_grp_id(x):
    grp_id = np.max([grp.get(e, -1) for e in x])
    if grp_id < 0:
        grp_id = max(grp.values())+1
        grp.update({e:grp_id for e in x})
    return grp_id

df['dupe_group_ix'] = df.A.apply(map_grp_id)

    A       dupe_group_ix
0   [A, B]              0
1   [D, X]              1
2   [B]                 0
3   [D, K]              1
4   [A]                 0
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Unless there's a speed improvement to using `apply` vs `map`, then `map(map_grp_id, na_action='ignore')` allows for nans. Also, I would suggest starting out with `df.loc[df['A'].map(len, na_action='ignore').eq(0), 'A'] = np.nan; df['dupe_group_ix'] = np.nan; df['dupe_group_ix'] = df['dupe_group_ix'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of @Allen's answer, much much faster (150ms vs 1min46sec) and allowing nans and empty columns.

```
        grp = {}

        def map_grp_id(x):
            for e in x:
                grp_id = grp.get(e, None)
                if grp_id is not None:
                    break
            else:
                grp_id = len(grp)
            grp.update({e: grp_id for e in x})
            return grp_id

        df.loc[df['A'].map(len, na_action='ignore').eq(0), 'A'] = pd.NA
        df['dupe_group_ix'] = pd.NA
        df['dupe_group_ix'] = df['dupe_group_ix'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
        df['dupe_group_ix'] = df[A].map(map_grp_id, na_action='ignore')
```